# sinon: how to mock a function that is returned from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, unit-testing, sinon

I'm trying to work with [simple-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git).  I need to write some unit tests, and to do so I need to mock out some functions using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/).  The problem I'm having is that my mocks don't propogate into my file under test.

For example, in the file under test, I have this:

```
const git = require('simple-git/promise')
function func () {
    var promise
    if (repo_exists()) {
        promise = git().silent(true).clone('http://github.com/me/my-repo.git')
    } else {
        promise = git('my-repo').silent(true).pull('origin','master')
    }

    promise.then(() => {
        // do more stuff
    })
}
```

In my test file, I've tried this:

```
const git = require('simple-git/promise')()
sinon.stub(git, 'silent').callsFake(() => {
  return {
    clone: () => {
      console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
      console.log('calling clone')
      console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('clone')
        resolve()
      })
    },
    pull: () => {
      console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
      console.log('calling pull')
      console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('pull')
        resolve()
      })
    }
  }
})
```

But the mocked functions don't get called. I assume the reason is that `require('simple-git/promise')` returns a function, which itself returns the object containing functions I want to mock, but I don't know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, when `git()` is called it returns a new object each time. Methods of this object are eventually proxied to an instance of `Git` (https://github.com/steveukx/git-js/blob/master/src/git.js)

As an option, you can stub internal `_run` method of  `Git.prototype` (the method responsible for scheduling the command for execution):

```
const Git = require('simple-git/src/git');

sinon.stub(Git.prototype, '_run').callsFake(function (command, cb) {
  console.log('called command', command)

  // to indicate success (will resolve eventual promise)
  cb.call(this, null, 'any message');

  // OR to indicate failure (will reject eventual promise)
  Git.fail(this, 'error message', cb);

  return this;
});
```

NB, non-arrow function under `callsFake` is essential to preserve `this` and `return this` is needed to comply with original behavior (https://github.com/steveukx/git-js/blob/master/src/git.js#L1271).

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work. [this](https://pastebin.com/zsQPN16) never gets called

Comment: @ewok the paste you provided is not available. This minimal example https://gist.github.com/svlapin/77c3844f5231d390b72725cf929562c7 works for me. It outputs `called command [ 'pull', 'origin', 'master' ]` and `all done, success` as expected

Comment: does that work if you pull the actual call to `pull()` out to a separate file and call the function that calls `pull()`?